# Using :autosave for has_one association: How to show the parent's errors when on the child's controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one, autosave, validates-associated

I have created a model that looks like this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :child, :child_id

  has_one :child, :class_name => 'Child', :autosave => true, :inverse_of => :parent

  #parent's validations

  validates_associated :child
end
```

And the child model is like:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :parent, :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, :inverse_of => :child

  validates_presence_of :parent
  #Other custom validations...
end
```

When I am at the new child's page, if the user does not choose a previously created parent for the child, I want to force him to create one at the same time he creates the child.
It's working fine if the user fills in all the data correctly for the child and the parent, but if the parent has any validation issue on a given field, the only message I get is: "Parent cannot be blank"

I wanted to show to the user the same message it would show if he was creating the Parent alone. That should be something like: "Field X of Parent is too short".

Is it possible, using validates_associated or with some similar helper?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question..
The problem was the line:

```
validates_associated :child
```

the **:autosave** and the **:inverse_of** options already do what I wanted. The validates_associated is unnecessary and, as I read, deprecated.

The **:autosave** option makes the parent save the loaded child that is associated, before saving the parent.

With the **:inverse_of** option, it will save the child, run its validations and, if something's wrong, add the child's errors to the parent without saying that the *"child is invalid"*.

Also..I did **not** use the **accepts_nested_attributes_for**. So I loaded the child and the parent at the parent's controller and then saved the parent:

```
@parent = Parent.new(params[:parent])
@parent.build_child(params[:parent][:child])

if @parent.save
    redirect_to(@parent ....etc.....
```

The errors flashed as I wanted.

Bye :)

Comment: trying to find where "validates_associated ... deprecated" is sourced... or is it more of 'in the minds of the community' type of deprecation?  thanks